# Should the company name given in google play developer console be registered?

Tags: google-play

I wanted to publish a game on Google play. Should the company name entered in the developer console be registered? Or can we simply give any name of our choice?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any name of your choice will be fine.

You do not have to have a registered company.

Cheers, and good luck -!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what if the name given is by chance already registered?

Comment: If they are already registered as a company, they aren't really going to care until you start making money. In that case, all they can really do is ask you to change your name, and take legal action if you do not. Now, there are some businesses that are already so big that if you happened to use their name, you would just get sued (You wouldn't, for example, want to call you dev shop "Apple Inc" ). So, do your research and make sure you aren't naming yourself after an already-registered business, and you'll be fine -!

Comment: It also won't hurt you to go ahead and buy a domain name for the company you plan to register, later -

Comment: As of 31st Aug 2023, you'll need a A D-U-N-S number. To get one, you need to be registered company.

Comment: @Humpity - that's worth adding as an answer. please do so you can get the updoots.

Comment: @rm-vanda - Because i don't know if it's true for every country.  Dun & Bradstreet have websites per country, probably with different rules. I've had it with Google, they just keep piling on more restrictions.